# Python, flask, babel- message, and e.g. Spanish - How to

Tags: python, flask, python-babel

I am utterly confused with trying to use babel with flask for language translation.

Lets assume the following.  A user has a preferance of spanish over english.  I have a variable that marks this:

```
g.user.default_language='sp'
```

Lets say I have to messages, one on english and the other in spanish that I want to display.
'Please' vs 'por fovor'

```
<html>
<h1>INSERT TRANSLATION HERE</h1>
</html>
```

Here is my base babel config file

```
[python: **.py]
[jinja2: **/templates/**.html]
extensions=jinja2.ext.autoescape,jinja2.ext.with_
```

So, where does 'Please' go and how is it mapped to 'por fovor' if user pref is spanish?

Then, how to I call from a template based on language profile?

Thanks

Comment: It is "por favor"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Flask-Babel](http://packages.python.org/Flask-Babel/) is really great project. If you looking for jinja, i18n and Flask on google, you will find some useful examples. Please see [docs](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates) for more info. Here I'll provide a little example:

**1. Create the translations dir**:

```
my_website/translations/pt/LC_MESSAGES/
my_website/translations/en/LC_MESSAGES/
```

Assuming that your site is in Portuguese and English. It is a manual way to do that. You'd better use `pybabel init` [command](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-BabelEx/).

**2. Create a file named messages.po (these files will contain translated strings):**

```
$ touch my_website/translations/pt/LC_MESSAGES/messages.po 
$ printf "msgid \"Hello world\"\nmsgstr \"Olá mundo\"" > my_website/translations/pt/LC_MESSAGES/messages.po
$ cat my_website/translations/pt/LC_MESSAGES/messages.po
```

It will create a file with the follow content:

```
msgid "HELLO WORLD"
msgstr "Olá mundo"
```

**3. Compile translation**

```
 $ pybabel compile -d translations
```

**4. Added line code this to your flask's main app file.**

```
app.config['BABEL_DEFAULT_LOCALE'] = 'pt_BR' #(context locale to load language).
```

**5. Use `_()` function in your jinja's template file in order to see *Olá mundo* string.**

```
<h1>{{ _('HELLO WORLD') }}</h1>
```

I hope it'll be useful.

Comment: What about translations within js code? Is it actually possible?

Answer (score 3):

Have you runned the pybabel translation as explained in the guide? http://packages.python.org/Flask-Babel/

And see http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#i18n-in-templates and http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/integration/#babel-integration

It seems you can simply use `_()`